# random function in C++

Tags: c++, function, random

Is there a function that generates k random numbers within a specified range.
For example I want 5 random numbers between 0 to 100, with or without replacement.

Comment: There is no built in function, but it is a rather simple one to write. Look at dynamically creating an array and the rand function. EDIT: I stand corrected look at first answer.

Comment: You mean something like this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/?

Comment: @drescherjm - You can call it 5 times.  It would generate a new random number each time.  You will need to give us more to work with if you don't understand the reason your code is not working.

Comment: @Ramhound. Sorry. I deleted my comment when I saw the boost answer which addresses the with or without replacement part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [std::generate_n](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) with either `rand()` or a generator from the new [C++11 random number generators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: C++11 random number generators: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution

Answer (score 3):

There is the Boost library, which you can use to generate random numbers, for example.
The following code generates 5 random numbers from [0, 100] **with replacement**:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp>

const int numWantedNumbers = 5;

int main()
{
    boost::random::mt19937 generator;
    boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> distribution(0, 100);
    std::vector<int> result;
    for (int i = 0; i < numWantedNumbers; ++i)
        result.push_back(distribution(generator));
}
```

If you want to generate the numbers **without replacement**, simply check if they are
still available:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp>

const int numWantedNumbers = 5;

int main()
{
    boost::random::mt19937 generator;
    boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> distribution(0, 100);
    std::vector<int> result;
    while (result.size() < numWantedNumbers)
    {
        int number = distribution(generator);
        if (std::find(result.begin(), result.end(), number) == result.end())
            result.push_back(number);
    }
}
```

**Note:** The rejection sampling in the example without replacement has the obvious drawback that longer vectors are quite difficult to create. Just try to draw 99 out
of 100 numbers, to see what I mean (or even better draw 9999 out of 10000). If this
is a problem, I would suggest to create a random permutation of all possible numbers
and then cut the vector at the requested size:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp>

const int numWantedNumbers = 5;

int main()
{
    boost::random::mt19937 generator;
    boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> distribution(0, 100);

    // Generate a vector with all possible numbers and shuffle it.
    std::vector<int> result;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; ++i)
        result.push_back(i);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; ++i)
    {
        int x = distribution(generator);
        std::swap(result[i], result[x]);
    }

    // Truncate to the requested size.
    result.resize(numWantedNumbers);
}
```

**Edit based on suggestion by [juanchopanza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661519/juanchopanza)**:

In C++11 manner, the last variant would look like this

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

const int numWantedNumbers = 5;

int main()
{
    std::random_device device;
    std::mt19937 generator(device());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribution(0, 100);

    // Generate a vector with all possible numbers and shuffle it.
    std::vector<int> result;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; ++i)
        result.push_back(i);
    std::random_shuffle(result.begin(), result.end());

    // Truncate to the requested size.
    result.resize(numWantedNumbers);
}
```

`g++-4.6` compiles it happily, if you add the `-std=c++0x` switch.

**Edit:** Make use of `std::random_shuffle()` (tanks to [James Kanze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/649665/james-kanze)).

Comment: That second algorithm could be very slow, if the number of numbers needed is close to the range.  A (sometimes) better solution would be to fill an `std::vector` with the possible values, call `std::random_shuffle` on it, and then take the first `n`.  This solution could require a lot of extra memory, if the number of numbers needed is very much smaller than the range.

Comment: You may want to add that most of this is available in C++11 too, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: @JamesKanze: I added a variant, which does not use rejection sampling.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Thanks, added a C++11 version, too.

Comment: @Mehrwolf And does a lot more work than necessary.  And may not give a random distribution anyway.  Replace the second loop with a call to `std::random_shuffle`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is a rand() function in C++ which can be used including cstdlib header file in your program.
You can implement your program using the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int max {100};
  int min {0};
  int number;
  int count = 5; //assuming that only 10 numbers we need to print
  srand(time(0));
  for(int i=1;i<=count;i++)
  {
      number = rand() % (max - min +1) + min;``
      cout<<number<<endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: `rand()`is not advised, use the C++11 random classes instead as recommended here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand