# How do i generate a random number between 1 and k which is not equal to n and m in c++?

Tags: c++, math, random, numbers

if n=2,m=3 and k=5 then answer could be 1 or 4 or 5. given k is always greater than or equal to 3. if k=3 and n=1,m=3 then answer will be 2.

Comment: Generate numbers between 1 and k-2, then add 1 with the result if after n and 2 is it is after m, something like that

Comment: Does this help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182441/random-function-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Assuming *m*≠*n*, there are four cases to consider:

1. (*m* < 1 or *m* > k) and (*n* < 1 or *n* > k):

   Just return a random number from 1 to *k*.
2. (1 ≤ *m* ≤ k) and (*n* < 1 or *n* > k):

   Generate a random number from 1 to *k*–1. If it is equal to *m*, output *k* instead.
3. (*m* < 1 or *m* > k) and (1 ≤ *n* ≤ k):

   Generate a random number from 1 to *k*–1. If it is equal to *n*, output *k* instead.
4. (1 ≤ *m* ≤ k) and (1 ≤ *n* ≤ k):

   Generate a random number from 1 to *k*–2. If it is equal to *m*, output *k*–1 instead, and if it is equal to *n*, output *k* instead.

If *m*=*n*, you could just set one of them to zero.

Answer (score 1):

without considering consumed time for long range this can counted as an answer( but non optimized one)

```
while( true)
{
 random = ( rand() % ( k + 1));
 if( random != n && random != m)
 {
  break;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ rand() creates a psudo random collection of 'random' numbers. So I recomend to set a seed value with srand(...). For another solution:

```
int main()
{
    // Generetes random seed for psudo random numbers.
    srand (1234);

    // Initialze variables
    int n, m, k, random;

    // Read in values
    std::cout << "Enter n:  ";
    cin >> n;
    std::cout << "Enter m:  ";
    cin >> m;
    std::cout << "Enter k:  ";
    cin >> k;

    // Generates a random number
    do {
        random = rand()% k + 1; // Random number from 1 to k
    }
    // Repeat if the random number is equal to n or m
    while (random == n || random == m);

    // The value
    cout<<"Number generated: " <<random<<"\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The important part is the do-while loop. The previous code is just the setup.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do it, and the choice depends on what the underlying requirements are.

```
// brute force (assumes that n < m):
int res = rand() % (k - 2) + 1;
if (n <= res) ++res;
if (m <= res) ++res;

// elimination:
int res = rand() % k + 1;
while (res == n || res == m)
    res = rand() % k;

// table lookup:
int results[] = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8 }; // n == 4, m == 7
int res = rand() % (sizeof results / sizeof *results);
res = results[res];
```

I'd probably go with the brute force approach; it always works, provided you know the relative order of `n` and `m`. A more sophisticated version would check which one is smaller, and swap them if necessary so that `n` is less than `m`.

Elimination is also always correct, and when `k` is large the loop will rarely be executed, so it might be slightly faster than brute force. When `k` is small it could loop many times. This approach is sometimes used in generating more complicated distributions such as a pair of coordinates that are within a circle (generate two coordinates and if they're outside the circle throw them away and try again).

Table lookup is probably not a good choice, but if you know the values of `k`, `n`, and `m` at compile time it could be slightly faster than either of the other two. Of course, for large values of `k` there's a lot of wasted space.